# Ancient dates (2 digits year) in VBA/VB6

Tags: vba, vb6

How can one create a `Date` variable in VBA that holds a date from a year before the year 100?

We have an VBA project that gets some of the values from a .NET project, for instance some dates. All of the values are strings and I have to convert them to the appropriate data type in VBA.
It happens that there is no date, so I get the .NET null date as a string like `0001-01-01T00:00:00`. With a current date I can just remove the "T" in the middle, put a space instead and give that string to the `CDate` function to get the `Date`. When I do that with the .NET null date I get 1/1/2001 as a result, because `CDate` assumes that the year 1 must be a shortened year and adds 2000 to it (it adds 2000 from year 1 to 29, and it adds 1900 from year 30 to 99).

So I thought I parse the string myself and use the `DateSerial` function to create the appropriate date, but this function does the same stuff.

I could do a string comparison and when I get the .NET null date I could convert it to the VBA null date, but that would only work when I really get the .NET null date. As soon as I get a date slightly higher than that (for instance `0001-01-02T00:00:00`), I'd had the same problem again.

I know that the null date in VBA is 12/30/1899, I know that I can create dates before that null date with the `CDate` function, but it seems to me, that I can't go below year 100, or can I?

Comment: Excel dates are not intended to go that far back, however you could just use integers (or even text) to create your own logic numbering system based on the specific period that you need.  More info [**here**](http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/earlydates.htm).

Comment: Thank you, I'm not using Excel, I use Access. I get this date in a code module and I need to show it on a form when there's a date.

Comment: I meant to say Access but it's the exact same idea; the basis of any solution will apply to any Office application.. Any resources you find for handling Excel date/times will apply to MS Access as well. (and there's a lot more out there for Excel.)

Comment: Since VB6 was tagged for this question as well, typically date controls (activeX files) usually have property settings for minimum date value as well as the format in which the date is presented.  While a controls default minimum date value might be 12/30/1899 by default, for example, I would think it could be set to 01/01/0000 but it depends on the control.  I don't know if this helps or not.

Comment: The Y2K problem solution in Windows is it uses nn30. Before nn30 it rounds down and nn31+ it rounds up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it seems that 1.1.100 is some kind of limit in VBA.

Internally the date is stored as double value so you can force older dates by calculating it in double variable and then copying it to date variable like this:

```
Public Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
  (lpDest As Any, lpSource As Any, ByVal cBytes&)

Public Function MyDateSerial(year As Long, month As Long, day As Long) As Date
  Dim d As Double

  If year >= 100 Then
    MyDateSerial = DateSerial(year, month, day)
  Else
    d = DateSerial(year + 100, month, day) - (DateSerial(200, 1, 1) - DateSerial(100, 1, 1))
    Call CopyMemory(MyDateSerial, d, 8)
  End If
End Function
```

But be careful because almost every operation with such value fails.
It would be probably better to use directly double variables for storing such data.
Or use custom structure like

```
Public Type MyDate
  year As Long
  month As Long
  day As Long
End Type
```